# C# Linq query not returning an Enumerable collection

Tags: c#, linq, blazor-server-side

I am new C# and EF and LINQ
I am trying to learning (much like a toddler) how to do this so apologies if this is obvious

I am getting a type conversion error when i create a LINQ query

```
namespace ABC.Pages
{
    public partial class AOmMainComponent
    {
        [Inject]
        MydbContext MydbContext { get; set; }



    public IEnumerable<OMSite> OMSites()
    {
            var Sites = from s in MydbContext.TblOms select new {SiteId = s.OMID, SiteName = s.OMSite };


        return (IEnumerable<OMSite>)Sites;

    }
}

public class OMSite
    {
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```
return Sites;
```

and I've tried

```
return (IEnumerable<OMSite>)Sites;
```

but neither work.Please can someone advise what i'm doing wrong?

thanks

john

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
var Sites = from s in MydbContext.TblOms select new {SiteId = s.OMID, SiteName = s.OMSite };
```

To:

```
var Sites = from s in MydbContext.TblOms select new OMSite {SiteId = s.OMID, SiteName = s.OMSite };
```

Particulary `select new {` -> `select new OMSite{`. After that `return Sites;` should work.

Your current code creates `IEnumerable` of [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) which can not be cast to  `IEnumerable<OMSite>` which your `IEnumerable<OMSite> OMSites()` method expects to be returned.

Comment: Thaks, this ha certainly solved one part of mmy problem.  But I still do not properly understanding getting the relationship between my code and model.

Comment: Thanks, this has certainly solved one part of mmy problem.  But I still do not properly understand the relationship between my code and the model.

when i try to run the code i get:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'ABC.Pages.Site' to 'ABC.Models.Ecosys.TblOm

I tried changing the Public class properties to match the field names in the model thinking that was the issue but apparently not.
I tried changing the class name to the table name but apparently not.

How do I do convert the public class to the EF table definition?

Comment: @johnm you need to create a new instance of `TblOm` and fill it fields with values from `ABC.Pages.Site`. C# is a strongly typed language so even if different classes have the same fields it does not mean they are the same.

Comment: So if I've understood you correctly I can pretty much call the public class anything i like?
But how do i create a new instance as you advise?

Comment: @johnm `new ClassName ....` as you do with `OMSite` now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the specific object in your projection:

```
var Sites = from s in MydbContext.TblOms select new OMSite {SiteId = s.OMID, SiteName = s.OMSite };
```

Your method is expecting you return `IEnumerable<OMSite>` and your query is creating an `IEnumerable` of a Anonymous types